# How to make an image map or hotspots on android

Tags: android, imagemap

Im making an app on android and need to make an image map or hotspots on an image so that if you click on a certain point of the image it does something.

[image: this is my image]

The image above is what i need it for. I need it so that if you click on facebook, it does one thing, and if you click on the others it does another.

And yes I have tried making them buttons but, that is not what I need, I am just trying to learn how to make an image map.

Comment: Image map or hotspots? :/ **Hotspot** is used to connect to the internet through a device with internet connection. If you have internet connection you can make a hotspot and others can connect to internet using your phone. Please make your question clear

Comment: @NewUser **Hotspot** is of two types, the one you said is correct, it used to connect with different device to share internet connection, second term of hotspot in webdevelopment is Image Mapping, so his question is correct

Comment: @Aamirkhan: Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the location of the areas in the image, it should be pretty easy.  Use a single ImageView.  Set an onTouch listener, and look for DOWN events.  Record the location.  Then on the UP event check that original location.  If the event location is within the bounds of an image, they just clicked it.

You can also do all of it in down, depending on whether you want the switch to happen when they first touch it or when they remove their finger (like clicks do).

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem that I wanted to use the image as hotspot means wherever you press,it will be having some functionality,
Here is a good source of Information,
http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/
Or You can refer this Page also,
[Define the layout perimeters manually,means i want to use my values to define the boundries of the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269046/define-the-layout-perimeters-manually-means-i-want-to-use-my-values-to-define-th)

Answer (score 0):

http://speckyboy.com/2008/07/21/20-amazing-jquery-plugins-and-65-excellent-jquery-resources/.

For the demo http://www.openstudio.fr/jquery-virtual-tour/salleformation.html

You can use jquery ,css, html for this purpose. I have downloaded the 2nd one in the link.

[image]

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Then in my activity display the same as

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
}
```

You can alsoo use the tool @ http://360flashtour.com/. Download the free version modify the source accordingly. You can create hotspots for image. Define action when images are clicked.

Comment: WebView is very heavy on resources... there are another ways mentioned in stackoverflow... Unfortunatelly, I would expect a component, which I could not find.

Comment: @Wooff i haven't found a better solution. Also this was long back in 2013 and i haven't been working on those now